# Dealing a hand of cards - incompatible types error

Tags: java, playing-cards, incompatibletypeerror

My problem is my professor gave us very detailed instructions on how to write this method:

"The dealAHand method has a loop that deals one Card (using the previous method - dealACard) at a time until it has dealt handSize Cards.  The String returned is a list of the Card objects in the hand – similar to the result of toString except that the String returned here contains only handSize Card objects. "

I'm trying to do what he said, but I keep getting incompatible type errors: in this incarnation, it says crd cannot be converted to Card[]. Additionally, this is the only time the variable handSize is mentioned.

I can also post my driver if needed. Any ideas? Please keep them intro-level.

```
public class Card {
    private Face face;
    private Suit suit;

    public Card() {//default
        face = Face.ACE;
        suit = Suit.HEARTS;
    }

    public Card(Card existingCard) {//copy
        //Card card = new Card(existingCard);
        face = existingCard.face;
        suit = existingCard.suit;
    }

    public Card(int n) {//professor written paramaterized
        face = Face.values()[n % 13];
        suit = Suit.values()[n % 4];
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        str = "the " + face + " of " + suit;

        return str;
    }
}

import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
    Card[] deck;
    int nextCard;

    public Deck() {//default, filling the deck
        nextCard = 0;
        deck = new Card[52];

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            deck[i] = new Card(i);
        }
    }

    public Deck(Card[] existingCard) {//copy
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            deck[i] = existingCard[i];
        }
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Random rn = new Random();
        Card temp;
        int num;

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            num = rn.nextInt(52);
            temp = deck[i];
            deck[i] = deck[num];
            deck[num] = temp;
        }
        nextCard = 0;
    }

    public Card dealACard() {
        nextCard++;
        return deck[nextCard - 1];
    }

    public String dealAHand() {//CHANGED
        int handSize = 5;
        Card[] crd = new Card[handSize];
        String hand = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < handSize; i++) {
            hand += crd[i].dealACard() + "\n";

        }
        return hand;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = " ";

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            str += deck[i].toString() + "\n";
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: crd is null in dealAHand.

Comment: The error is at return crd;

Comment: I've tried just having Card[] crd; it still says incompatible

Comment: The function is declared to return Card. You're attempting to return a null Card[].

Comment: That almost worked. Now I have 2 more problems, though. It's printing a memory location rather than the cards and I misread the instructions: it has to return a String. I'm going to change the above to reflect it, but I'm having trouble combining a String with crd.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise the `crd` array with a size. Java arrays are fixed size.
Try declaring `handSize` first then constructing the array to have that size, like this - `Card[] crd = new Card[handSize];`

Also change the return type of `dealAHand` to return the array of Cards.

Comment: That almost worked. Now I have 2 more problems, though. It's printing a memory location rather than the cards and I misread the instructions: it has to return a String. I'm going to change the above to reflect it, but I'm having trouble combining a String with crd.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! Thank you to everyone who responded. :-)

```
public String dealAHand() {
    int handSize = 5;

    String hand = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < handSize; i++) {
        hand += dealACard() + "\n";
    }
    return hand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a PROBLEM with your "professor written parameterization," or however you characterized it.  value%4 and value %13 CANNOT BOTH BE CORRECT.  Consider the case where I order things thus:

AS 2S 3S 4S 5S . . . JS QS KS AH 2H 3H . . . JH QH KH AD 2D 3D . . . etc.

In this case, DIVIDING by thirteen tells us which suit we're in (S, H, D, or C), whereas MODULO thirteen tells us the rank.  Alternatively, if we organize as follows:

AS AH AD AC 2S 2H 2D 2C . . . QS QH QD QC KS KH KD KC

then DIVIDE BY FOUR gives the rank and MODULO four gives the suit.

value%4 and value %13 ARE SIMPLY INCORRECT.  That itself is a QUITE FUNDAMENTAL error.  This can NEVER work.